# Enable a parameter to accept more than one type as input, while being more focused than using "Any"

Tags: kotlin

I have a method that takes in `value` which must be of type `Boolean`, `Float`, `Int`, `Long`, or `String`. Is there a way make this method only accept those types for `value`, rather than take in  `Any` and handle incorrect values, like I've done with with the `when()` statement?

```
fun putValue(key: String, value: Any) {
        when (value) {
            is Boolean -> putBoolean(key, value)
            is Float -> putFloat(key, value)
            is Int -> putInt(key, value)
            is Long -> putLong(key, value)
            is String -> putString(key, value)
            null -> return
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You could overload the function so that the allowed types become available to the compiler at compile time.

Steps:

1. Remove your current `putValue` function
2. Rename all existing type-specific functions from `putXXX` to `putValue` (they will all have the same name, and they will be overloaded on their argument type)

Answer (score 0):

The only interface they all have in common (furthest down the inheritance hierarchy) is [`Comparable<T>`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-comparable/index.html). So you could restrict the type of `value` like this using [Generics](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html) with an upper bound:

```
fun <T: Comparable<T>> putValue(key: String, value: T?) {

    when (value) {
        is Boolean -> println("Boolean")
        is Float ->  println("Float")
        is Int -> println("Int")
        is Long -> println("Long")
        is String -> println("String")
        null -> return
    }
}
```